# Есть кусок Java кода, у меня не получается его переписать на PhP

Tags: php, java

Кусок java кода:

```
public static String hashPass(String password, String salt) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        md.update(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] bytes = md.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] var5 = bytes;
        int var6 = bytes.length;

        for(int var7 = 0; var7 < var6; ++var7) {
            byte b = var5[var7];
            sb.append(Integer.toString((b & 255) + 256, 32).substring(1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception var9) {
        var9.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Мой код:

```
function hashPass($hash, $salt) {
    $ar = hash('sha512', $hash, $salt, true);
    $size = strlen($ar);

    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $str .= substr(dechex(((int)$ar[$i] & 255) + 256), 2);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Но почему-то ничего не выводит!

Comment: Пробовал и на python, но не получилось

Comment: Минимум ошибка в том, что hash не работает с солью, и принимет только 3 параметра. Вам нужна hash_hmac.  Либо должна быть конкатинация  соли и сообщения.

Comment: Теперь вывод 30102900008020240080295804680000800910816207053000250106800810041008008007235030350401000470000755004422000056206879103955080732