# Как получить строку из байтов?

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь сделать дехешер вот такого чуда - `9gn2kfvt9gbptel56u3bjgirumgjfjm1ffo9gl1e7c90etvis0un9i4f4g13jvih`.
Но у меня не получается

Мой код:

```
def hashpass(passsw, salt):
    m = hashlib.sha512()
    m.update(salt.encode('utf-8'))
    m.update(passsw.encode('utf-8'))
    byte = m.digest()
    len_byte = len(byte)
    print('Колицество символов - ' + str(len_byte)) 
    res = ''
    for n in range(0, len_byte):
        hex_byte = hex((byte[n] & 255) + 256)
        res += hex_byte 
        print(hex_byte)

hashpass('45345345', 'plvbutgseltevdjj')
```

Вывод:
0x173
0x15b
0x16c
0x1c5
0x1d9
0x115
0x18c
0x165
0x110
0x1a9
0x1cf
0x11f
0x193
0x16c
0x16b
0x159
0x142 ...

Код этой функции на Java (нужно реализовать то же самое на Python):

```
public static String hashPass(String password, String salt) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        md.update(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] bytes = md.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] var5 = bytes;
        int var6 = bytes.length;

        for(int var7 = 0; var7 < var6; ++var7) {
            byte b = var5[var7];
            sb.append(Integer.toString((b & 255) + 256, 32).substring(1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception var9) {
        var9.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь из хеша получить оригинальную строку?

Comment: Нет, я пытаюсь создать хеш выше указаного типа, чтобы сравнить его с оригиналом

Comment: Есть функция chr вообще. Но с utf-8 всё сложнее, наверное.

Comment: @РоманБойчук, объясните подробнее ТЗ и что должно получиться. Непонятно как связана строка в вопросе с хешем в коде. Кст, чтобы получить hex строку от хэша можно вместо `.digest()` использовать `.hexdigest()`

Comment: Я пытаюсь переписать java код.

Comment: тут java https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117336

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Магическая конструкция `Integer.toString((b & 255) + 256, 32).substring(1)` - это перевод числа в систему счисления с базой 32 (в которой цифры от 0 до 9 и от a до v - аналогично как в 16-ричной системе цифры от 0 до 9 и от a до f), и взятие последней цифры<sup>*</sup>.

Можно было записать короче: `Integer.toString(b % 32, 32)`.

На python эту же операцию для одного байта можно выполнить так:

```
import string

alphabet = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase

encoded = alphabet[b % 32]
```

В вашем коде нужно поменять цикл перекодировки:

```
import string

alphabet = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase

def hashpass(passsw, salt):
    # ...
    res = ''
    for b in byte:
        encoded = alphabet[b % 32]
        res += encoded 
        # print(encoded)
    return res

print(hashpass('45345345', 'plvbutgseltevdjj'))
```

---

* - строго говоря, цифр начиная со второй, но т.к. для b в диапазоне от 0 до 255 после сложения с 256 в системе с базой 32 в любом случае получится 2 цифры (от 80 до fv), то это будет всегда последняя цифра